# Slurm Worker node can not connect to Master node

Tags: ubuntu, cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

I am trying to set up a simple Slurm cluster. The setup is the following: two virtual machines, one will be the master (and also a worker), let's call it Master (ubu18gpu-210), and the other one will be the other worker, let's call it Worker (ubu18gpu-211).

The name of both machines is the exact output of `hostname -s` command.

Installation of all requirements and Slurm is already done in both machines. I can even run jobs on the Master node. However, the problem I am facing is that the Worker can not connect to the master.
I have Slurmdbd, Slurmctld and Slurmd Daemons running without any issues in the Master node. The Worker node is also running the Slurmd Daemon but the log is always reporting the same error:

```
[2021-09-22T10:52:54.049] error: get_addr_info: getaddrinfo() failed: Name or service not known
[2021-09-22T10:52:54.049] error: slurm_set_addr: Unable to resolve "ubu18gpu-210"
[2021-09-22T10:52:54.049] error: Unable to establish control machine address
[2021-09-22T10:52:54.049] error: Unable to register: No error
```

I have reviewed many times the configuration file `slurm.conf` and I think that is correct, at least the part dedicated to the definition of the Master and the Nodes:

[slurm.conf](https://pastebin.com/DvwPARFy)

The weird thing comes when displaying the information in the Master node with `sinfo` and `scontrol` commands. I will paste the outputs here:

```
sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
debug*       up   infinite      2   idle ubu18gpu-[210-211]


scontrol show nodes ubu18gpu-[210-211]
NodeName=ubu18gpu-210 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=6
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUTot=6 CPULoad=0.00
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:1
   NodeAddr=192.168.23.210 NodeHostName=ubu18gpu-210 Version=21.08.0
   OS=Linux 4.15.0-117-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 20:02:41 UTC 2020
   RealMemory=23531 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=8695 Sockets=1 Boards=1
   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=1 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=debug
   BootTime=2021-09-21T16:13:38 SlurmdStartTime=2021-09-22T11:08:39
   LastBusyTime=2021-09-22T11:08:39
   CfgTRES=cpu=6,mem=23531M,billing=6,gres/gpu=1
   AllocTRES=
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s

NodeName=ubu18gpu-211 CoresPerSocket=6
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUTot=6 CPULoad=0.00
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:1
   NodeAddr=192.168.23.211 NodeHostName=ubu18gpu-211
   RealMemory=23531 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=22257 Sockets=1 Boards=1
   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=1 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=debug
   BootTime=None SlurmdStartTime=None
   LastBusyTime=2021-09-22T11:08:42
   CfgTRES=cpu=6,mem=23531M,billing=6,gres/gpu=1
   AllocTRES=
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
```

It seems that is detecting correctly the Worker node although I think that is because of the information in the configuration file.

I don't really know what may be happening... I can correctly ping from one to the other machines so there is a connection between them. I have also opened the 6817-6818 Slurm default ports without any improvements. I have also followed the [Official Troubleshooting Guide](https://slurm.schedmd.com/troubleshoot.html) and everything seems correct.

In addition, I have synchronized time between machines using Network Time Protocol (NTP). The Master hosts the NTP server and the output from the Worker is:

```
ntpq -c lpeer
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*192.168.23.210  LOCAL(0)        11 u   38   64  377    0.255   -0.518   0.299
```

Which I assume is the correct behaviour

Does Anyone know what may be happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that luckily I have been able to find the solution. I don't know if is something specific from my configuration but in each of the nodes I have to update the `/etc/hosts` file adding the Master name and IP as:

```
192.168.23.210 ubu18gpu-210 ubu18gpu-210
```

Comment: Sound like there is no DNS or it is not working correctly.